# Jenkins: How to fail stage when test fails?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a stage in my pipeline that is running some UI tests currently this is the behaviour I get:

- If the tests pass the stage goes green the next stage runs, and at
  the end the build goes green.
- If a test fails the stage goes green, the next stage runs, and at the
  end the build is yellow (unstable)

How can I make it so that instead of moving on to the next stage if a test fails the pipeline is failed?

This is the stage of my pipeline, I've tried adding a post section but even when a test fails it reports success.

```
                stage('UITests') {
                    steps {
                        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'env_file', variable: 'envFile')]) {
                            sh '''
                            cat $envFile > .env.dev
                            make run_tests
                            '''
                            }  
                    }
// Fail build if test fail 
                    post{
                            success {
                                echo "UI Tests passed moving to Build stage"
                            }
                            failure {
                                error "UI Tests Failed, stopping the build"
                            }}
                }
```

In the Jenkins log for the stage I can see when a test fails I get

> error Command failed with exit code 1.

This doesn't happen when a test passes so is there a reason the post block is always going to success?

Answer (score 1):

The sh step returns the same status code that your actual sh command: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

You can get this status code, assign its value to a variable and then fail with a custom message:

```
def statusCode = sh script:"cat $envFile > .env.dev && make run_tests", returnStatus:true
if (statusCode != 0) {
  error 'UI Tests Failed, stopping the build'
}
```

Comment: How would I put that in the pipeline? When I tried I replaced the sh block in my steps with this but I got an error: WorkflowScript: 86: Expected a step @ line 86, column 1.
   if (statusCode != 0) {
   ^

Comment: @DoctorWho It is Groovy code, and therefore must be within a `script` block in a declarative pipeline.

Comment: I forgot the `script` block I've tried that but I still get an exit code of 0 when a test fails. `stage('UITests') {
steps {
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'env_file', variable: 'envFile')]) {
script {
def statusCode = sh script:"cat $envFile > .env.dev && make run_test", returnStatus:true
echo "THE STATUS CODE IS ${statusCode}"
if (statusCode != 0) {
error 'UI Tests Failed, stopping the build so you can investigate the issue.'
                                 }
                        }
                            }  
                    }
}`

Comment: I guess the problem is not in the pipeline but in the makefile. Could you check if it is printing the error message and returning a 0 status code?

I've tried in a pipeline and the message in Jenkins is "script returned exit code 1" not "error Command failed with exit code 1" so i guess the error is inside make or the makefile.

Comment: Yes it's the makefile, do you know how I can get it to return the exit code? the make file calls a sh script that does some setup and then runs the tests by `yarn run uiTests`

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909999/run-makefile-command-from-bash-script-and-return-error-result-code